# How to open multi-module project with IntelIiJ IDEA?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have the following project structure in IntelIiJ IDEA:

> Website
>
> > Main Source [Empty]
> >
> > Unit Test [Maven]
> >
> > Sketches [Empty]

I have always been able to open this and have the structure shown properly. I've cloned this repository to a different computer now and am only able to open it the first time after clone. When I try to open the project the next day, it opens with only the Unit Test folder. Is there any way I can get it to consistently open with all three folders? It says it can't open my Main Source folder.

Comment: 1. How are you "cloning" your repository? 2. It might be due to the fact that the other folders are empty and so IntelliJ ignores them...not sure why it would though...

Comment: Another thought that came to me was that you haven't defined your Main Source folder as a `Source` folder in your `Project Structure`

Comment: @Harmelodic how do i go about defining it?